# Reorder parts of String separated by specified character to reverse order

Tags: java, android

I am having a String   `Australia@2@India@30@UK@4@USA@43`
 I need to reverse such as `USA@43@UK@4@India@30@Australia@2`

This is just a sample string, in reality the String is having atleast 20@ symbols.

I have tried `new StringBuilder(newString).reverse().toString();` but the ouput I am getting is very weird.

Comment: It is not reverse.`@USA@43` reverse is `34@ASU@`

Comment: Yeah but the way in which I need output is been specified...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, this is what you can try: -

```
    String str = "Australia@2@India@30@UK@4@USA@43";

    String[] arr = str.split("(?<![a-zA-Z])@(?<!\\d)");

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        builder.append(arr[i] + "@");
    }

    // Remove the last `@`
    builder = builder.replace(builder.lastIndexOf("@"), 
                              builder.lastIndexOf("@") + 1, "");

    System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

**OUTPUT**: -

```
USA@43@UK@4@India@30@Australia@2
```

---

**Explanation of Regex: -**

**`(?<![a-zA-Z])@(?<!\\d)`** - Split on `@` not preceded by any `alphabet` and not `succeeded` by any `digit`

Answer (score 0):

REverse means that ABC is reversed to CBA ....
The result you get is not weird is the just the characters in the oposite order.
You might you split based on @

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure if this is the best solution.I am sure there could be a lot better solutions but below code give the desired output:

```
String s="Australia@2@India@30@UK@4@USA@43";
        String[] sArr = s.split("@");
        String rev="";
        String temp="";
        for(int i= sArr.length-1;i>=0;i--){
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(sArr[i]);
            if(scan.hasNextInt()){
                temp='@'+scan.next();
            }
            else if(scan.hasNext()){
                rev+=scan.next()+temp;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(rev);



OUTPUT:USA@43UK@4India@30Australia@2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy solution I could come up with. It employs the String.split and StringBuffer classes.

```
public class TestStrings {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
            String sampleStr = "Australia@2@India@30@UK@4@USA@43";

        String [] strArr = sampleStr.split("@");

        StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer();
        for(int i=strArr.length-1;i>=0;i=i-2)
    strBuffer.append(strArr[i-1]+"@"+strArr[i]);


        String finalStr = strBuffer.toString().replaceFirst("[@]$", "");
        System.out.println(finalStr);
       }
}
```

// OUTPUT
// USA@43UK@4India@30Australia@2